# Как изменить Markup клавиатуру в сообщении?

Tags: node.js, telegram-bot, telegraf

Есть телеграм бот, который отправляет сообщение с картинкой, текстом и кнопками.

```
return ctx.replyWithPhoto(photo_url, {
        caption: text,
        parse_mode: "HTML",
        reply_markup: Markup.inlineKeyboard([
            [Markup.button.callback(text_butt1, 'clickbtn1')],
            [Markup.button.callback(text_butt2, 'clickbtn2')],
        ]).reply_markup,
    }).catch((err) => err);
```

При нажатии на кнопку, мне нужно изменить кнопки, а текст и картинку оставить.

```
        return ctx.editMessageReplyMarkup({
        reply_markup: Markup.inlineKeyboard([
            [Markup.button.callback(locale.start_menu.buttons.links, 'none')],
            [Markup.button.callback(locale.start_menu.buttons.my_profile, 'none')]
        ]).reply_markup,
    }).catch((err) => err);
```

Такой код работает, но вместо замены, просто удаляет клавиатуру.

```
        return ctx.editMessageCaption(ctx.update.callback_query.message.caption ,{
        parse_mode: "HTML",
        reply_markup: Markup.inlineKeyboard([
            [Markup.button.callback(locale.start_menu.buttons.links, 'none')],
            [Markup.button.callback(locale.start_menu.buttons.my_profile, 'none')]
        ]).reply_markup,
    }).catch((err) => err);
```

Такой код тоже работает, но мой видоизмененный текст с курсивом и подчеркиванием превращается в обычный.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Чтобы изменить только клавиатуру, нужно использовать `editMessageReplyMarkup`

В вопросе неправильная запись кода

```
    return ctx.editMessageReplyMarkup({
    reply_markup: Markup.inlineKeyboard([
        [Markup.button.callback(locale.start_menu.buttons.links, 'none')],
        [Markup.button.callback(locale.start_menu.buttons.my_profile, 'none')]
    ]).reply_markup,
}).catch((err) => err);
```

Правильно будет, вот так:

```
return ctx.editMessageReplyMarkup(
Markup.inlineKeyboard([
    [Markup.button.callback(locale.start_menu.buttons.links, 'none')],
    [Markup.button.callback(locale.start_menu.buttons.my_profile, 'none')]
]).reply_markup).catch((err) => err);
```

Comment: Если как вы утверждаете, это ответ на ваш вопрос, дополните его, опишите суть решения: [edit]